# TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to reproduce the following code:

```
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set.iloc[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set.iloc[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set.iloc[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set.iloc[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
Xpred = np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()] + [np.repeat(0, X1.ravel().size) for _ in range(6)]).T
# Xpred now has a grid for x1 and x2 and average value (0) for x3 through x13
pred = svm.predict(Xpred).reshape(X1.shape)   # is a matrix of 0's and 1's !
plt.contourf(X1, X2, pred,
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))

plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set.loc[y_set == j, 0], X_set.loc[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
```

But get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6e8fac406f24> in <module>
     13 plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
     14 for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
---> 15     plt.scatter(X_set.loc[y_set == j, 0], X_set.loc[y_set == j, 1],
     16                 c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
     17 plt.title('SVM (Test set)')

...
...

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _invalid_indexer(self, form, key)
   3338             "cannot do {form} indexing on {klass} with these "
   3339             "indexers [{key}] of {kind}".format(
-> 3340                 form=form, klass=type(self), key=key, kind=type(key)
   3341             )
   3342         )

TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>
```

I've tried used iloc instead of loc but I have no luck. Does anyone have any feedback? Thanks is advance!

Comment: Can you try `X_set.loc[y_set == j, X_set.columns[0]]` and similarly `X_set.loc[y_set == j, X_set.columns[1]]`?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Here is why it worked: `loc` expects *labels* rather than *integers*; and in case your columns are not labelled with integers `0..N-1` then `loc` fails. Therefore we pass the label i.e. *name* of the 0'th (and 1st) column to `loc` and it is happy then.